# inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation python3.8

Tags: python

I cannot find the inconsistency of tabs and spaces in my coding. Everything up to and including the line:

```
if params ['trigger'] == 'ema3':`
    conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema3'])
```

works perfectly fine, but the rest of the file does give me an error. I do not know what I did wrong, given that I copied the line above and just changed the number. Could you help me out, please?

```
def populate_buy_trend(dataframe: DataFrame, metadata: dict) -> DataFrame:
            """
            Buy strategy Hyperopt will build and use.
            """
            conditions = []

            # GUARDS AND TRENDS
            if 'trigger' in params:
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema3':
                    conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema3'])
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema5':
                    conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema5'])
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema10':
                    conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema10'])
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema21':
                    conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema21'])
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema50':
                conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema50'])
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema100':
                conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema100'])
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema120':
                conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema120'])
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema150':
                conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema150'])
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema180':
                conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema180'])
                if params ['trigger'] == 'ema200':
                conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema200'])
```

Comment: You have a tab in the `== 'ema3':` line. You should replace all tabs in your indents with 4 spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Several of the if statements do not have an indented body in the bottom half of your code. Indent the

```
conditions.append(dataframe['close'] > dataframe['ema50'])
```

and all the subsequent lines that start with `conditions`